# How to adjust text alignment inside table

Tags: tables

I am wondering how can I adjust the alignment of text inside the table. I want, for example, make the left column of the table have shifted text in some rows which represent like headings. How can I do this to make a certain row shifted to the right a little bit. I appreciate your help.

Comment: See the `tabularray` package documentation for how to create tables in LaTeX.

Comment: Your problem has nothing with editor., just to your table design. That be clear, what you after, please provide an MWE, which show your problem. In general, you should select desire column types and in case, if some cell should have different content alignm use multicolumn  cell or `\makecell[<alignment>} {....}` etc.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of ways to achieve this. Here are just two.

1. Add space before each element in the column, and remove the space before the headings. Automatic insertion is done using `>{<stuff>} l`, while `\multicolumn{1}{c}` avoids this insertion.

   [image]

   ```
   \documentclass{article}

   \usepackage{booktabs,array}

   \begin{document}

   \begin{table}
     \centering
     \newcommand{\rowhead}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{l}{\bfseries #1}}%
     \begin{tabular}{ >{\hspace*{1em}}l c }
       \toprule
       \multicolumn{1}{c}{\bfseries Heading} & \bfseries Stuff \\
       \midrule
       \rowhead{Subheading 1}             \\
       Something weird here           & 2 \\
       Something completely different & 3 \\
       Who knows                      & 4 \\
       \addlinespace
       \rowhead{Subheading 2}             \\
       Something weird here           & 5 \\
       Something completely different & 6 \\
       Who knows                      & 7 \\
       \bottomrule
     \end{tabular}
     \caption{Some table}
   \end{table}

   \end{document}
   ```
2. Add an extra column that denotes the space, and set the headings across both columns. You can adjust the width of the first column to increase/decrease the space. Note that the column separation (`\tabcolsep`) is still in play here.

   [image]

   ```
   \documentclass{article}

   \usepackage{booktabs}

   \begin{document}

   \begin{table}
     \centering
     \newcommand{\rowhead}[1]{\multicolumn{2}{l}{\bfseries #1}}%
     \begin{tabular}{ l l c }
       \toprule
       \multicolumn{2}{c}{\bfseries Heading} & \bfseries Stuff \\
       \midrule
       \rowhead{Subheading 1}               \\
       & Something weird here           & 2 \\
       & Something completely different & 3 \\
       & Who knows                      & 4 \\
       \addlinespace
       \rowhead{Subheading 2}               \\
       & Something weird here           & 5 \\
       & Something completely different & 6 \\
       & Who knows                      & 7 \\
       \bottomrule
     \end{tabular}
     \caption{Some table}
   \end{table}

   \end{document}
   ```

Comment: Thank you so much!